# Get column name by index in SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

This code

```
slickgrid.onDblClick.subscribe(function(e){         
    var cell = slickgrid.getCellFromEvent(e);
    console.log(cell.row, cell.cell);
});
```

prints `0, 0` if I double click the first row, on the first column - and so on.

But since column order can change at any given time, I need to get its name using its index.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just get a reference to the current columns array:

```
grid.getColumns()[cell.cell]
```

Comment: Ha, I figured it out a few seconds before your answer, for real :) cheers.

Comment: How do I get  header cells ?